# glDrawRangeElements doesn't draw the chosen range

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I want to draw two cubes with a rectangle between them, so I stored vertices data into a vbo,then i created an ebo(Element Buffer Object) to avoid extra vertices(42 vs 12).
I need to draw them separately, because I want the rectangle to reflect the up cube, doing stencil test and disabling the depth mask while drawing the rectangle.
I thought I could draw the first cube with a glDrawElements call

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

then, to draw the ractangle I'm trying to use glDrawRangeElements

```
glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, 41, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

but it is just drawing the base of the cube.

For the last cube I am using the same draw call of the first, just inverting it in the z axis.

I think i did something wrong with glDrawRangeElements parameters, because i tried doing just one call for the first cube and then the rectangle

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 42, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

and it works.

What's wrong with that glDrawRangeElements call?

EDIT: I solved by not using a glDrawRangeElements call but a simple glDrawArrays call, rearranging the rectangle's vertices to draw two triangles;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glDrawRangeElements` doesn't do what you think it does. The *functionality* of `glDrawRangeElements` is *identical* to `glDrawElements`. The only difference is that `glDrawRangeElements` takes a range that acts as a *hint* to the implementation as to which vertices you'll be using.

See, because your indices are in an array, the driver doesn't automatically know what section of the vertex data you're using. You use `glDrawRangeElements` as a potential performance enhancer; it lets you tell the driver what range of vertices your draw call uses.

Nowadays, `glDrawRangeElements` is pointless. See, the range used to matter, because implementations used to read vertex arrays from CPU memory. So when you did a regular `glDrawElements`, the driver had to read your index buffer, figure out what the range of vertex data was, and then copy that data from your vertex buffers into GPU memory and then issue the draw call. The `Range` version allows it to skip the expensive index reading step.

That doesn't matter much anymore, since now we store vertex data in buffer objects on the GPU. So you shouldn't be using `glDrawRangeElements` at all.

Comment: So how can  draw just a part of the elements?

Comment: what's the modern way to render a range of indices from an elements array? given the array resides on the gpu...?

Comment: @samawaat: Please read the answer. `glDrawElements` *is* how you draw a range of indices. The `Range` functionality was only ever an optimization, one that hasn't been relevant for decades.

Comment: @NicolBolas <3 i figured it out after i commented, i was confused about the offset parameter.